# Check if string contains substring at index

Tags: python, string, substring

In Python 3.5, given this string:

```
"rsFooBargrdshtrshFooBargreshyershytreBarFootrhj"
```

and the index `17` -- so, the `F` at the start of the second occurrence of `FooBar` -- how can I check that `"FooBar"` exists? In this case, it should return True, while if I gave it the index `13` it should return false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a very simple way to do this without using any additional memory:

```
>>> s = "rsFooBargrdshtrshFooBargreshyershytreBarFootrhj"
>>> s.startswith("FooBar", 17)
True
>>>
```

The optional second argument to `startswith` tells it to start the check at offset 17 (rather than the default 0).  In this example, a value of 2 will also return True, and all other values will return False.

Answer (score 2):

You need to slice your original string based on your substring's length and compare both the values. For example:

```
>>> my_str = "rsFooBargrdshtrshFooBargreshyershytreBarFootrhj"

>>> word_to_check, index_at = "FooBar", 17
>>> word_to_check == my_str[index_at:len(word_to_check)+index_at]
True

>>> word_to_check, index_at = "FooBar", 13
>>> word_to_check == my_str[index_at:len(word_to_check)+index_at]
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print("rsFooBargrdshtrshFooBargreshyershytreBarFootrhj"[17:].startswith('Foo')) # True
```

or in common

```
my_string[start_index:].startswith(string_to_check)
```

Comment: It’s correct but use more memory than the @Moinuddin Quadri’s answers, and a little slower ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Tom Karzes approach, as a function

```
def contains_at(in_str, idx, word):
    return in_str[idx:idx+len(word)] == word

>>> contains_at(s, 17, "FooBar")
>>> True
```

Comment: Thanks for the credit, but I realized there's a much better way to do this.  See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def checkIfPresent(strng1, strng2, index):
    a = len(strng2)
    a = a + index
    b = 0
    for i in range(index, a):
        if strng2[b] != strng1[i]:
           return false
        b = b+1
    return true

s = "rsFooBargrdshtrshFooBargreshyershytreBarFootrhj"
check = checkIfPresent(s, Foobar, 17)

print(check)
```

Comment: Really not pythonic! Only useful to understand some basic concepts.

Comment: Indeed slicing maybe more useful (didn't think about it... This was the first thing that came to me) but this is still an answer to his question...